# Navigation Menu

Tags: napili

I am building new communities site using Napili and struggling with the menu items. I dont see how to create a child menu item for one of my top level items. I am sure at one point I saw an option to link to parent category but now for some reason I dont see any way to do this. Documentation talks about site map but also I dont see an overview section where I can view or modify the site map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is delivered in the Spring'17 release:

> ## [Customize Community Navigation with Nested Menu Items](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_networks_menu_hierarchy.htm)
>
> The new Menu Label type in the Navigation Menu component lets you create parent headings for your navigation menu and nest items underneath.
>   Nested navigation menu
>
> [image: Nested navigation menu]
>
> Add a menu item, and set the type to Menu Label. Nest other menu items underneath by dragging them to the right under the menu label.
>
> > You can’t nest navigational topics under menu labels.
>
> [image: Navigation Menu component in Community Builder]

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub topics in the community management got this .

Under the navigational topics you can add a child topic for each of the parent topic .