# Navigate menu on Napili - create sub objects

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, community-builder, partner-communities

Is it possible to create sub object pages similar to sub topics on navigation menu in the Napili template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is same as - [Navigation Menu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158639/navigation-menu/160547#160547)

This feature is delivered in the Spring'17 release:

**Customize Community Navigation with Nested Menu Items**

The new Menu Label type in the Navigation Menu component lets you create parent headings for your navigation menu and nest items underneath. Nested navigation menu

[image]

Nested navigation menu

Add a menu item, and set the type to Menu Label. Nest other menu items underneath by dragging them to the right under the menu label.

You can’t nest navigational topics under menu labels.
Navigation Menu component in Community Builder
[image]